# Dropdownlist wrong display in ie

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer

I am using the DropDownList control (ASP.NET , VB) in IE6, 7 and 8.

My DropDownList control is set to 200px width, but the item list are longer, and display cropped.

I've tried using tooltips with attribute("title") but it didn't work.

What should i do?

(I bound items from a datatable so I dont have the `<select>` `<options>` in the html)

Comment: Just remove the fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

You can Overwrite the Width of Drop down by JQUERY once page rendered.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#dropdownID").addClass("ddlwidth")
});
```

make a class in CSS

```
.ddlwidth{width:500px !important;}
```

!important will overwrite width with current value